# should can i add foreign key reference to a pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

i have three tables menu, food, menu_food, i have the following migration code to create a table menu_food

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->integer('food_id');
$table->integer('menu_id');
```

The table food, menu also has two increment id.

i'm wondering should i add foreign keys on food_id and menu_id as reference to id of the menu table and food table?

-----update------
i've tried the answer but has errors

php artisan migrate

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_foodcall`.
  `#sql-198c_1e1` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
   (SQL: alter table `menu_food` add constraint `menu_food_food_id_foreign` f
  oreign key (`food_id`) references `food` (`id`))



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_foodcall`.
  `#sql-198c_1e1` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Yes :) It is not needed but makes your queries faster since keys are indexes.

Comment: its recommended to let auto-increment jobs to database engine too.
Add the constraint, then simply pass all parameters except id and it will be the next one auto.

Comment: Show us how you added the foreign keys. Don't forget to make you columns `->unsigned()`.

Comment: after add -> unsigned (), it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add `foreign` keys as reference to respective table `id`. Something like this:

```
$table->foreign('food_id')->references('id')->on('food');
$table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menu');
```

You can see the Laravel documentation **[here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)**

Comment: Well you don't need foreign keys for it to work. It is recommended.

Comment: Yes if you used unsigned in previous table then you should used it also. `->unsigned();` use `unsigned`.